# Scaling an image in a WordPress post

Tags: images

I am currently building a WordPress theme and when I add an image using the add media button, I'm able to choose a scaling percentage to allow the image to get bigger or smaller within the modal pop up box.

It seems that the standard themes that ship with WordPress allow the user to do this, so there must be some functionality that is included with these themes. It seems when I inspect the code that there is an alternative width and height attribute added to the image when percentage scaling is added to an image within the context of a theme like Twenty Eleven.

Is it straightforward to add this functionality to themes built from scratch as I am doing?

Comment: It's built into the WordPress Core - so in every WordPress install this functionality will be there. Are you wanting to customize it in some way? That's probably more difficult and is going away in version 3.9 which comes out in April.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It appears that the functionality doesnt do anything in my theme which I have built from scratch ie when I resize my image to 60% then the image does not get resized accordingly. I would not be wanting to customise it. My guess was that there was some kind of hook within the twentyeleven theme to activate this functionality that I am missing in some way. It appears I am wrong about that however